# Performing an action after user has captured an image

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac, cwac-camera

I want to perform an action after user has captured an image.But i see nothing happens after I captured an image.I am using below code and [CWAC-Camera](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) library.Content written inside `onPictureTaken` is the action which i want to perform after user captured an image-

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PictureCallback {

private final String TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT = "camera_fragment";
private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
ImageView switchToVideoOpen,camera;
private Boolean isVideoOpen = false;
CircleImageView togglePlay;
RelativeLayout actioncamera;
View blackTransparent;
byte[] datacamera;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_camera);
    switchToVideoOpen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.switchToVideoOpen);
    camera=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.camera);
    togglePlay = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.togglePlay);
    actioncamera = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.audio_actions_container);
    blackTransparent = findViewById(R.id.blacktreansparent);

    CameraFragment f = new CameraFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.preview_view, f, TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT)
            .commit();

    f.setHost(new SimpleCameraHost(this));

    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            takePicture();
        }
    });
    switchToVideoOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!isVideoOpen) {

                isVideoOpen = true;
                switchToVideoOpen.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_stop);
                camera.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_icon);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                takeVideo();
            }
            else{
                isVideoOpen = false;
                switchToVideoOpen.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_icon);
                camera.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_stop);
                stopVideo();
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

}

private void takePicture() {
    CameraFragment f = (CameraFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT);
    if (f != null && f.isVisible()) {
        f.takePicture();
    }
}
private void takeVideo() {

    CameraFragment f = (CameraFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT);
    if (f != null && f.isVisible()) {
        try {
            f.record();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
private void stopVideo() {

    CameraFragment f = (CameraFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_CAMERA_FRAGMENT);
    if (f != null && f.isVisible()) {
        try {
            f.stopRecording();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) {
    String pictureFile = GFileUtils.getGCameraDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+
            G.getFileNameForGMedia(G.General.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO);
    if (pictureFile == null) {

        return;
    }
    blackTransparent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    actioncamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    togglePlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    datacamera=bytes;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPictureTaken()` will not be called, because that is not how the library works.

The documentation covers how you can [override photo saving](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera#overriding-photo-saving) and receive the `byte[]` from the camera for doing whatever it is that you plan on doing. It involves creating your own `CameraHost` (whether from scratch or by subclassing `SimpleCameraHost`) and overriding `saveImage(PictureTransaction, byte[])`.